# Getting a unique RegistrationID of a Android device to C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

To use **C2DM** for my application i registered new **Gmail account** with Google as a **Sender** account.
Now i am confused that how to get **RegistrationID** for my device and how to **associate** it with the Sender account. i want to install this application on **multiple Andorid phones** so **do i need unique RegistrationID for each Android phone** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sides to C2DM:

1. Your server stores registration IDs for the users. It requests n auth code from Google's servers (using ClientLogin) and then uses that auth code to send push messages.
2. Your Android app requests a registration ID from Google's servers. It is sent one over C2DM. It sends it to the server, to be stored there (so messages can be sent to it).

This tutorial describes it all in detail, with code:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

A registration ID is like the address on a postal envelope - it describes where a push message is to be sent, the destination. So yes, you need one for each device. Registration IDs are actually assigned to a specific app (name space) on a specific device.

Comment: that is a Helpful Tutorial. I still have one confusion. if i develop app and install it on 10 android phones then will i be able to send a message from server to a particular android phone. and do i need to pro-grammatically get RegistrationID and register with my Sender account... Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Yes as ollie said, its like an address for the phone. If you want to send a push to a particular phone, use the device registration id and push to that.

Comment: If you want to send messages to lots of devices owned by one user, then your server will need to store a registration ID for every device. So in that scenario the user record on your server will have multiple registration IDs stored (one for each device)

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the boiler plate C2DM code from http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ ,when the app registers, it will recieve a registration id , which you have to save it in a database on your server. The registration id can change so you have to notify the server, every time it changes.

To get the registraton id use

```
C2DMessaging.register(this, "email id");
```

Comment: `C2DMessaging.register(this, "email id");`  is the "email id" is one which i already registered with the Google for using C2DM